# Trying to connect to Admin Cloud Storage API from a Cloud Function 2nd gen

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

i'm trying to follow a simple Admin Cloud Storage API but i'm getting an error.
I'm trying to access cloud storage in cloud functions.

This is the documentation code found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start):

```
const { initializeApp, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getStorage } = require('firebase-admin/storage');

const serviceAccount = require('./path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');

initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: '<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com'
});

const bucket = getStorage().bucket();

// 'bucket' is an object defined in the @google-cloud/storage library.
// See https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/latest/storage/bucket
// for more details.
```

My code looks like this:

```
const { initializeApp, cert } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getStorage } = require("firebase-admin/storage");

const serviceAccount = require("./...");

initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: "...",
});

const bucket = getStorage().bucket();

console.log(bucket);
```

But i'm getting an error:

> functions: Failed to load function definition from source:
> FirebaseError: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully.
> It may have a syntax or runtime error

What could be causing this error. I'm running on the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Cloud Function you don't need to initialize the Admin SDK with a Service Account.

You can do as follows (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app)):

```
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");

initializeApp();
```

If you want to access a bucket, you should do it from within a Cloud Function. Below are two examples:

1. The *writeBucketOnUpload* Cloud Function is [triggered by an upload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events?gen=2nd) to the default bucket. It prints the bucket name
2. The *getDefaultBucketName* Cloud Function is an [HTTPS one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd) which returns the default bucket name when you call it as a REST API endpoint (e.g. with curl or with a browser)

---

```
// Import function triggers from their respective submodules:
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const { onObjectFinalized } = require("firebase-functions/v2/storage");
 
const { log } = require("firebase-functions/logger");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getStorage } = require("firebase-admin/storage");

initializeApp();

exports.writeBucketOnUpload = onObjectFinalized((event) => {
  const fileBucket = event.data.bucket; // Name of the Storage bucket containing the file
  log(fileBucket);
  return true;
});

exports.getDefaultBucketName = onRequest((req, res) => {
  const fileBucket = getStorage().bucket();
  res.send({ bucketName: fileBucket.name });
});
```

---

If you want to trigger a Cloud Storage Cloud Functions from a different bucket than the default one, you should configure the CF as follows:

```
exports.writeBucketOnUpload = onObjectFinalized(
  { bucket: "your-bucket-name" },
  (event) => {
    const fileBucket = event.data.bucket; // Storage bucket containing the file.
    log(fileBucket);
    return true;
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, very insightful. Building on this, i have another issue which i would appreciate your insight on. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76948880/how-to-iterate-over-firebase-storage-using-cloud-functions