# How to iterate over Firebase Storage using Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm try to apply Google Cloud Vision to files in my Firebase Cloud Storage using Firebase Cloud Functions.
The storage structure is bucket > images > userID > image. There are multiple users and they have multiple images in their folder. I want to be able to map/forEach the userID and then map/forEach the images. I am struggling to figure out how to go about this.

I have tried: [List Objects In a Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files) but its not working, probably because its for GCP rather than Firebase functions.

How do I iterate over objects in a Firebase bucket?

Comment: The underlying products are the same for GCP and Firebase. They are basically identical except for the tools you use to build and deploy code.  If something isn't working for you, you should show your [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) to get feedback on that. Otherwise it's likely that this question will get marked as a duplicate of another question that asks essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should note that Google Cloud Storage **does not have genuine "folders"**. In the Cloud Storage console, the files in your bucket are presented in a hierarchical tree of folders (just like the file system on your local hard disk) but this is just a way of presenting the files: there aren't genuine folders/directories in a bucket.

The Cloud Storage console just uses the different parts of the file paths to "simulate" a folder structure, by using the "/" delimiter character.

This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders) on Cloud Storage and gsutil explains and illustrates very well this "illusion of a hierarchical file tree".

---

Therefore you can very well use the asynchronous [`getFiles()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) method to list the files in your bucket, **but**:

- For each file you'll get **its full path** and it will be up to you to extract the parent "folders" names and the file name from this path in order to get the desired result (i.e. mimic the `forEach` loops mentioned in your question)
- In addition you'll also get the "folders" names so you need to ignore them

As an example, the following HTTPS Cloud Function lists all the files (and "folders") in your default bucket: it logs them in the Cloud Console Log and it returns an array of all these files.

```
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const { log } = require("firebase-functions/logger");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Storage.
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getStorage } = require("firebase-admin/storage");

initializeApp();

exports.getFilesList = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const fileBucket = getStorage().bucket();
  const [files] = await fileBucket.getFiles();

  const filesArray = [];
  files.forEach((file) => {
    log(file.name);
    filesArray.push(file.name);
  });

  res.send({ bucketName: filesArray });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

buckets are very similar to filesystems. i believe in firebase you're looking for something like /images/[userID]/[filename]

it should be pretty easy just to use your framework to do this. it's unlikely you'll need any ADDITIONAL firebase functions.